# Redirecting a logged in user to a page while allowing them to still visit the homepage using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm playing around with ( teaching myself ) rails and I am using the following code

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
        if user_signed_in?
            redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'
        end
    end
end
```

As a result of the code above when the user is logged in they get redirected to the 'dashboard' ( which is great) but they can't access the homepage. How can I fix this ? I'm still very new to ruby/rails so still getting acclimated with the syntax etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirect all logged in users to dashboard index only after sign in:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'index', :controller => 'dashboard')
    end
   end`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You are redirecting all request from logged in users to dashboard page. So any logged in user when trying to visit home page would be redirected to the dashboard page. What you have to do is when the user logs in through devise you have redirect it to the dashboard. Please check [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

**Sample Code:**

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  signed_in_root_path(resource)
end
```

Hope it helps.